# Passing string[] between fragment. How to do that?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

fragment1:

```html
lst.ItemClick += delegate(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e) {

    var intent = new Intent (this, typeof(TracksByGenres));
    intent.PutStringArrayListExtra ("keys", items);
    StartActivity (intent);
   };
```

TracksByGenres is fragment2

> Error:The best overloaded method match for
>   `Android.Content.Intent.Intent(Android.Content.Context, System.Type)'
>   has some invalid arguments atnew Intent (this,
>   typeof(TracksByGenres));

Fragment2:

```html
public async override void OnActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstancesState)
  {
   base.OnActivityCreated (savedInstancesState);
   paramKey = Intent.Extras.GetStringArray ("keys").ToString();

   lst = View.FindViewById<ListView> (Resource.Id.lstHome);
```

Where is incorrect?

Comment: Is TracksByGenres a class inheriting from Activity ?

Comment: No. It is fragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var intent = new Intent (this, typeof(TracksByGenres));
            intent.PutStringArrayListExtra ("keys", items);
            StartActivity (intent);
```

Above snippet is to create an instance of a new Activity and launch it. Second parameter , `typeof(TracksByGenres)` should be actually `typeof(A class inheriting from Actiivty (not fragment))` This is causing the exception.

Inorder to switch Fragments, you need to use `FragmentTransaction` . Here is a tutorial about [how to manage fragments](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/fragments/part_2_-_managing_fragments/).

EDIT : Example of passing Data to Fragment , asked in comment

```
public class TracksByGenres :Fragment
{
  string mData;
  public void AddData(string data)
  {
     mData=data;
  }
  public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
      // inflate layout and store in variable
       //you can use data here
       // myTextView.Text=mData;
   }
}
```

Then In Activity,

Creating First Fragment, adding Data and Loading in FrameLayout

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTx = this.FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
TracksByGenres fragment = new TracksByGenres();

fragment.AddData("Xamarin is awesome");
// The fragment will have the ID of Resource.Id.fragment_container.
fragmentTx.Add(Resource.Id.fragment_container, fragment);

// Commit the transaction.
fragmentTx.Commit();
```

Replacing the fragment with a new Fragment, adding data. In this example Im using the same fragment for ease.

```
TracksByGenres aDifferentDetailsFrag = new TracksByGenres();

aDifferentDetailsFrag.AddData("Xamarin is awesome");

// Replace the fragment that is in the View fragment_container (if applicable).
fragmentTx.Replace(Resource.Id.fragment_container, aDifferentDetailsFrag);

// Add the transaction to the back stack.
fragmentTx.AddToBackStack(null);
```

// Commit the transaction.
    fragmentTx.Commit();

Comment: Get data from fragment 1. How to do that? I just saw that your code is passing data